# pass php data into modal (foundation 4)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have a MySQL database that stores all my uploaded music.

I have a link that lists all the upload tracks by that artist.

> Artist - Track Name - Status [delete]

Now the [delete] button is linked to `song_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['song_id']; ?>`.

I want this to load the confirmation page (song_delete) into a modal.

This is my HTML for the modal.

```
<div id="deleteMusic" class="reveal-modal medium">
<h2>Request to delete<span style="color:#F7D745;"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
<p class="lead">Are you sure you want to delete this song? Please allow 2 full business weeks for deletion.</p>
<span style="float:right;"><a href="#" class="button close-reveal-modal cancelbtn">Cancel</a>    
<a href="#" class="button submitbtn">Submit</a>  </span>

<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you are asking for 
found here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html

**Firing a Reveal Modal with Ajax Content**

```
<button data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="http://server/song_delete.php">
    Click Me and open Modal for confirmation
</button>
```

or

```
<a href="http://server/song_delete.php" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
      Click Me and open Modal for confirmation
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, is there anyway to do it using more of the Foundation framework? I dont really know javascript or ajax all that well.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the full title of your issue. I looked at the framwork. I didn't see any ajax. I'll look again for you.